# SOLR indexing performance with large amount of data

Tags: indexing, solr

i have an indexed of 10 millions documents, then as per the new requirement i need to add extra field in my solr schema.
So my question is what would be the ideal approach? i mean simply add field in schema and re-index the whole data? or just some partial index? or something else?.

Answer (score 0):

The data has to be submitted regardless of what you do, so the answer would probably depend on the size of the rest of your fields. If they are small, just add the field and reindex everything.

If there's a very large field present, it might be more effective letting Solr fetch the content internally (i.e. a partial update) instead of submitting it over the network, but that would require that you already have all fields defined as stored or with doc values.

It's impossible to say exactly, so you'll have to perform a small test with a small number of documents to see exactly how performance is with your dataset.